# python slice method does not always return a new address in memory?

Tags: python

```
x = [1,2]
for i in range(4):
    y = x[:]
    print id(y)
```

the results are like:

```
4392626008 4392835408 4392626008 4392835408
```

My purpose is to copy x each time and do something with a new container. My python is `version 2.7.5` and OS system is `Mac OS X 10.9`, does it matter?

Comment: It could be that because the scope of `y` is only inside the `for` loop, and hence the memory address can be reused.

Comment: Why should `y` have a different address each time ??? What you are trying to do is unclear.

Comment: like I said. I need a new container

Comment: @AndyLiu you are getting a new container... It just happens to be re-using the address of an old one that you've informed Python it can garbage collect by not having any references to the previous created slice(s) any more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never keeping all occurrences of `y` around - you're just rebinding the name `y` to a copy of `x` each time in the loop, so that by a later point in the loop - Python might well choose to reallocate the same area of memory for the new slice. And since `id` in CPython returns the memory address, you may get the same...

```
for i in range(4):
    # Rebinding `y` inside the loop - making the object available for garbage collection 
    y = x[:] 
    print id(y)
```

If you were to keep all `y` about, then you will get unique `id`s in CPython:

```
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> ys = [x[:] for _ in range(4)]
>>> map(id, ys)
[40286328, 40287568, 40287688, 40287848]
```