# Python 3 set equality

Tags: python, set, equality

I use Python3.

`{1,2} == {1,2}` returns True, but `{1,2} is {1,2}` returns false. It seems reasonable as id({1,2}) is different from another id({1,2}).

However why  `id({1,2}) == id({2,1})` returns true? Even `id({1,2}) == id({2,1,3})` returns true.

Comment: `{2,1,3}` gets created, its id is fetched,  then it gets garbage collected. `{1,2}` is then created and the same id is assigned to the new object. If you held on to references this wouldn't happen.

Comment: You should post this as an answer @StevenRumbalski

Comment: Another candidate for duplicate [Unnamed Python objects have the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id).