# shallow copy in python

Tags: python, list, shallow-copy, copy-assignment

I am a little confused on how shallow copy works, my understanding is when we do `new_obj = copy.copy(mutable_obj)` a new object is created with elements of it still pointing to the old object.

Example of where I am confused -

```
## assignment
i = [1, 2, 3]
j = i
id(i[0]) == id (j[0])  # True
i[0] = 10
i  # [10, 2, 3]
j  # [10, 2, 3]

## shallow copy
k = copy.copy(i)
k   # [10, 2, 3]
id(i) == id(k)  # False (as these are two separate objects)
id(i[0]) == id (k[0])  # True (as the reference the same location, right?)
i[0] = 100
id(i[0]) == id (k[0])  # False (why did that value in that loc change?)
id(i[:]) == id (k[:])  # True  (why is this still true if an element just changed?)
i   # [100, 2, 3]
k   # [10, 2, 3]
```

In shallow copy, isn't `k[0]` just pointing to `i[0]` similar to assignment? Shouldn't `k[0]` change when `i[0]` changes?

Why I expect these to be same, because -

```
i = [1, 2, [3]]
k = copy(i)
i  # [1, 2, [3]]
k  # [1, 2, [3]]
i[2].append(4)
i  # [1, 2, [3, 4]]
k  # [1, 2, [3, 4]]
id(i[0]) == id (k[0])  # True
id(i[2]) == id (k[2])  # True
id(i[:]) == id (k[:])  # True
```

Comment: But lists are not immutable objects.

Comment: `int`s are immutable objects, so you set a new object at `i[0]`.

Comment: Why do you expect `i[0]` to still point to `k[0]`? The two lists are different ones, hence an update in one list, does not reflect in the other

Comment: shallow copies are the same as deep copies as long as there are not nested arrays.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated the question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `ints are immutable objects, so you set a new object at i[0]`  Then what about that case in assignment(where the same is done)?

Comment: @SirGoPythonJavaCppRubythe3rd oh, that makes sense.
Could you explain why `id(i[:]) == id (k[:])` is True in the shallow copy example(even after k has a new element)?

Comment: `id(i[:]) == id (k[:])  # True  (why is this still true if an element just changed?)`. This is probably a cpython implementation detail. `id` for lists is based on memory address, which presumably is reused, because `i[:]` is immediately garbage collected. The two lists are not the same object.

Comment: @AniMenon It's something about the == operator. If you print the id of `i[:]` and `j[:]`, you can see that they are different. Using the `is` operator instead of the `==` operator on `i[:]` and `j[:]`, it will return False.

Comment: The `==` operator is not doing anything strange. Try creating a tuple `id([1,2]), id([3,4])` and they are the same value.

Comment: @HåkenLid interesting, `creating a tuple id(i[:]), id(k[:]) and they are the same value`.. then why: `id(i[:]), id(k[:])
 => (48079624L, 48079624L)` while `id(i[0]), id(k[0]) =>
(45444848L, 45443240L)` ? _(i.e. when `i => [100, 2, [3, 4]]` and `k => [1, 2, [3, 4]]`)_

Comment: @AniMenon The garbage collector reclaims `i[:]` *immediately* since it is an anonymous object. Then, `k[:]` is created in the same spot. It doesn't happen if you maintain references to each individually. See my answer below.

Comment: @MattMessersmith yes, reading it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `id(i) == id(k)  # False (as these are two separate objects)`

Correct.

> `id(i[0]) == id (k[0])  # True (as the reference the same location, right?)`

Correct.

> `i[0] = 100`
>
> `id(i[0]) == id (k[0])  # False (why did that value in that loc change?)`

It changed because *you changed it in the previous line*. `i[0]` *was* pointing `10`, but you changed it to point to `100`. Therefore, `i[0]` and `k[0]` now no longer point to the same spot.

Pointers (references) are *one way*. `10` does not know what is pointing to it. Neither does `100`. They are just locations in memory. So if you change *where* `i`'s first element is pointing to, `k` doesn't care (since `k` and `i` are *not* the same reference). `k`'s first element is still pointing to what it always was pointing to.

> `id(i[:]) == id (k[:])  # True  (why is this still true if an element just changed?)`

This one's a bit more subtle, but note that:

```
>>> id([1,2,3,4,5]) == id([1,2,3])
True
```

whereas

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> id(x) == id(y)
False
```

It has to do with some subtleties of garbage collection and id, and it's answered in depth here: [Unnamed Python objects have the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id).

Long story short, when you say `id([1,2,3,4,5]) == id([1,2,3])`, the first thing that happens is we create `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Then we grab where it is in memory with the call to `id`. However, `[1,2,3,4,5]` is anonymous, and so the garbage collector *immediately* reclaims it. Then, we create another anonymous object, `[1,2,3]`, and CPython happens to decide that it should go in the spot that it just cleaned up. `[1,2,3]` is also immediately deleted and cleaned up. If you store the references, though, GC can't get in the way, and then the references are different.

### Mutables example

The same thing happens with mutable objects if you reassign them. Here's an example:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
>>> b = copy.copy(a)
>>> a[0].append(123)
>>> b[0]
[1, 2, 3, 123]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 123], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 123], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a[0] = [123]
>>> b[0]
[1, 2, 3, 123]
>>> a
[[123], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 123], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The difference is when you say `a[0].append(123)`, we're modifying whatever `a[0]` is pointing to. It happens to be the case that `b[0]` is pointing to the same object (`a[0]` and `b[0]` are references to the *same* object).

But if you point `a[0]` to a *new* object (through assignment, as in `a[0] = [123]`), then `b[0]` and `a[0]` no longer point to the same place.

Comment: @AniMenon Excellent, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 2):

In Python all things are objects. This includes integers. All lists only hold references to objects. Replacing an element of the list doesn't mean that the element itself changes.

Consider a different example:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.v)

>>> i = [MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3)]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> j = i[:] # This achieves the same as copy.copy(i)

[1, 2, 3]
>>> j[0].v = 7
>>> j
[7, 2, 3]
>>> i
[7, 2, 3]

>>> i[0] = MyInt(1)
>>> i
[1, 2, 3]
>>> j
[7, 2, 3]
```

I am creating a class MyInt here which just holds an int.
By modifying an instance of the class, both lists "change". However as I replace a list entry, the lists are now different.

The same happens with integers. You just can't modify them.

Answer (score 0):

- In the first case `j = i` is an assignment, both j and i point to the same list object.
   When you change an element of the list object and print i and j, since both i and j point to same list object, and it is the element and not the list object which has changed, so both will print the same output.
- In the second case `k = copy.copy(i)` is a shallow copy, in which a copy of list object and copy of nested references is made but the internal immutable objects are not copied.
  A shallow copy doesn't create a copy of nested objects, instead it just copies the reference of nested objects. Please refer this https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy
- Thus i and k have different set of references pointing to the same immutable objects. When you do `i[0] = 100`, the reference in list i points to a new int object with value 100, but the reference in k still references the old int object with value 10.

Comment: @Ani Menon Welcome

Comment: "In shallow copy immutable objects are copied, but for all mutable objects their references are copied." Not true shallow copies do the same thing to mutable and immutable objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please review