# How to create separate instances of a hash algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

`hashlib` contains implementations for hash algorithms. Unfortunately two consecuting calls to `hashlib.sha256()` do not produce two different instances of SHA256 but the same one: If called twice `hashlib.sha256()` will return the same object each time. So apparently we have a singleton here

This is bad in a all situations where any kind of concurrency is required. Additionally this is very bad in situations where you want to provide a hashing object to some algorithm. In my case: Tests fail as the same object is reused instead of creating a new one.

My question: How an I create two instances of SHA256 (or any other hash algorithm)?

Example:

```
import hashlib

print(hashlib.sha256())
print(hashlib.sha256())
```

This will output something like:

```
<sha256 HASH object @ 0x7fb3611b4710>
<sha256 HASH object @ 0x7fb3611b4710>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get two different `<sha256 HASH object @ 0x101f9a260>` objects ... can you provide the code you are using to determine this? I suspect you are misusing `id` (rather, falling into the all too common trap). Note, for me `hashlib.sha256() is hashlib.sha256()` returns `False`

Comment: That's strange. I get 'False' as well, but it seems to be the same object.

Comment: It is not the same object then. It is exactly as I suspected, you are printing the object's representation, which include's it's `id`, i.e. in this example `0x7fb3611b4710`, because in CPython, **as soon as the reference count reaches zero**, the object is reclaimed. The object only exists long enought to be passed into `print`. The CPython runtime optimizes allocations, is is perfectly happy to reuse the memory from the last object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unnamed Python objects have the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id)

Comment: Interesting. GC apparently works a bit differently in all other programming languages I ever dealt with. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the second hash-object is created after your first hash-object was garbage-collected. Therefore they can have the same memory address. In `hashlib.sha256() is hashlib.sha256()` the first one can't be garbage-collected since it has to be compared first. You can save the hash-objects in varibles to keep them alive:

```
h1 = hashlib.sha256()
h2 = hashlib.sha256()
print(h1 is h2)

[Output]
False
```