# similar address to different variable in python . Why?

Tags: python, memory

in my institute i was told that every variable in python has it's own memory address and memory address in each variable is different.They proved it by using id() command , they showed us

```
>>>a=10
>>>b=20
>>>id(a)
94349304104992
>>>id(b)
94349304105312
```

by showing this statement they proved us how both the memory location are different.

then i was trying the same thing with my linux terminal and got some weird answer when i tried....

```
>>>id(999)
139978570234704
>>>id(10001) 
139978570234704
>>>id(9999)
139978570234704
>>>id(100001)
139978570234704
>>>id(99999)
139978570234704
>>>id(1000001)
139978570234704
>>>id(999999)
139978570234704
>>>id(10000001)
139978570234704
```

after trying all this i found that this all numbers i pointing toward same location and i can not understand why this is happening only with this kind of number

beside this when i tried the same thing on windows cmd it worked fine. Every values got allocated to the different location

Comment: Please first explain why you think it should work differently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unnamed Python objects have the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id) and [Why is the id of a Python class not unique when called quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20753364/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> `id`(*object*)
>
> Return the "identity" of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** This is the address of the object in memory.